# How to implement a client for file uploading to a WSO2-ESB proxy service?

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

I config an ESB proxy:

```
ESB Proxy --> inSqquence --> outSequence --> clone --> VFS
```

How to implement a client for file uploading to a WSO2-ESB proxy service?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure ESB to upload files to a location using VFS transport listener and sender. Refer to [Sample 254: Using the File System as Transport Medium (VFS)](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15471427) where in the outSequence the response is saved to a directory using an endpoint with vfs file address. To clone the messages going through the ESB you can use [Clone mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Clone+Mediator).